# How to save video in Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is it possible to capture video and audio in Silverlight5 and save it as movie in any video format?

Comment: Are you using elevated priviledges? Are you using OOB? This will define what you can do with storage.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight 5 can automatically detect video and audio capture devices, which you can open operations on using [the System.Windows.Media.CaptureDeviceConfiguration class and associated classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602282%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

http://chris.59north.com/post/Audio-recording-and-encoding-in-Silverlight.aspx has info on how to use those classes to save the audio to a Stream (as well as compressing it), which you can then save to disk.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1751-how-to-access-a-video-and-snap-a-picture-from-webcam-in-silverlight.aspx has similar info on how to access video and save images from webcams on to disk using Silverlight.

[Pro Silverlight 5 in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234792) (excerpt on [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=PJmgeIdZT3YC&pg=PA448&lpg=PA448&dq=capture%20video%20and%20audio%20in%20Silverlight5&source=bl&ots=VtN0loilwc&sig=WlfQ-vJxdUYmh3LbmO6qxel3Tn4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yEZQT7bCO6WIsAKs3pGrDg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)) has more information on how to do this.

Comment: My question is not how to capture video or audio. I want to know, how to record video and audio to hard disk using .net technologies. :)

Comment: I think you need to expand on what you're trying to do in your question then.  It currently is about capturing video and audio.

Comment: I have web cam and microfone. I want to find any way to record myself's video and speach to hard disk. It would be better if it was possible using web technologies.

Comment: @dlanod If you'd bothered to finish reading the question, you'd have seen the part where he said "and save it as movie in any video format"

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing quite a lot of searching and I have yet to find any samples of anyone actually saving video.  The best I have been able to come up with is saving a sequence of images.  That doesn't really sound like a good solution